# How do we pass Execution from an HTTP Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, httphandler

We created our own redirect httpHandler that accepts all requests (verb="*", path="*"):

```
  <system.webServer>        
         <handlers>
            <remove name="Redirect" />
        <add name="staticFileHandler" path="*.html" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" verb="GET,HEAD"  />
        <add name="Redirect" path="*" verb="*" type="RedirectModule.RedirectHandler, 
RedirectModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, publicKeyToken=77c8b6b494e19eeb" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />         
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

In the http handler we have code that checks the URL and redirects if the browser it is mobile. In this case if the browser is not mobile or we've already redirected we would like to continue with execution of the static files and display their content.

The problem we're having is that because the http handler we are using accepts all requests the StaticFileHandler doesn't process the HTML file and we always get a white screen.

How do we pass execution from the httphandler to a staticFileHandler through code or the web.config.

Appreciate any help.

Orit

Answer (score 3):

A handler should only decide *how* to process a file extension (either physical or logical), not *when*. I think you meant to create a module.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449232/151445) answer by Jon Galloway and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) MSDN article on Handlers and Modules.

edit: Also, check out [ASP.NET/Mobile](http://www.asp.net/mobile)'s first How-To.  It shows how to accomplish this in both Web Forms and MVC.