# Efficiently Upload Output to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient, webrequest

I have created a Simple Aspx Page to Log the Output of a Process running on a Remote Machine.

My url is:`.com/Log.ashx?Data=SomeString`

Should I use WebRequest or a WebClient?
What is more efficient and less resource intensive?

I would need to do this about 20 times in a minute. The ashx file does not show any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither one is more efficient than the other.  WebRequest just offers you more functonality than WebClient.  if WebClient exposes enough functionality for what you need than go with that.  If it doesn't then use WebRequest.

Comment: A suggestion : Read this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449132/http-handler-vs-http-module  Consider httpmodule.  Are you writing the server side code?  I think so, but am a little unclear.

Comment: http://blog.blackballsoftware.com/2010/10/10/persisting-querystring-values-using-httpmodule/