# How important are modules and handlers?

Tags: asp.net

Well, I'm just learning ASP.Net, and after reading some books I found that there are this things called Modules which tweak a Request and Handlers that (I think) tweak a response. The problem is that I can't understand how they really work, so I prefer just skip this part and come back to them when I get a bit more comfortable with the ASP.Net framework.

My question is, are they a big part of this framework? Am I going to use them a lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET modules and handlers are definitely important, but typically they are secondary to pages and services: so it is reasonable to focus on pages and/or services first.

As your understanding grows, modules and handlers will probably start to make more sense when you revisit them.

Having said this, [a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6449132/1810429) explains ASP.NET modules & handlers about as simply as one could hope for.